# Chamar função javascript no managed bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Estou utilizando a framework JSF com primefaces 6.0 e como sou novo, estou com dificuldades chamar um javascript ao finalizar um método de um bean com escopo @RequestScoped. Como posso fazer isso? Tem algum outro jeito utilizando este escopo?

Quero chamar um script para mostrar uma notificação de feedback do resultado para o usuário.

Lembrando que pode acontecer algum erro ao iniciar a página no @PostConstruct init, método inicializador do bean, então preciso chamar o script sem action de um botão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas o Javascript é realmente necessário?

Já que você usa Primefaces, acredito que o ideal seria ter um componente p:messages ou p:growl na tela e adicionar a sua mensagem pelo bean ao finalizar o método utilizando:

```
//... Seu código
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Feedback para o usuário"));
```

Eu geralmente encapsulo esse código em um método adicionarMensagem() de uma superclasse, mas fica a seu critério.